# To which game would these dice belong?

Tags: identify-this-game

Someone on Facebook happened on these old dice.

Characters are engraved on some of them :

**345 L D** (?) **HILLTOP**, and some symbols.

Can someone identify the game from which they come?

[image: Dice of unknown origin]

Comment: L and D could be roman numerals. Is hilltop written out, or a picture of a hilltop (or the roman numeral "C")

Comment: Could they be casino dice?

Comment: The serial numbers, edges, and color indicate casino dice, yeah.

Comment: I imagine those are logos representing different casinos

Comment: I have to agree with you that they are casino dice. Not being a casino fan, I checked the result of a Google image search and found the resemblance very convincing. Therefore, if @Karl. i.e. the first person to suggest this, were to post this as an answer, I would credit you with the correct answer...

Comment: @Rober Miller thank you.  The answer provided is a good one so you may as well accept that as I can't add anything to it.  I don't really care about reputation points for myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These dice aren't specific to a game. These appear to be casino dice, as seen in this online store listing:

[image: casino dice store listing]

In order to make them as fair as possible, they have sharper edges than those you normally find in board games<sup>[1]</sup>, and the pips aren't carved out of the dice.

In addition to the markings being in line with many casino dice, the pip style appears to be common in casino dice.

---

1. Board game dice are commonly made using a different process which requires them to be tumbled or polished to remove aberrations, but this can wear out the dice unevenly. [How dice are made](https://www.gmdice.com/blogs/dnd/how-are-dice-made).